# Comment button wordpress

Tags: wordpress, button, comments

I'm editing my website for add a comment button and view comments button.

I call the PHP wordpress function but don't work.

I'm adding the button in place of Jetpack sharedaddy module.

This is the code:

```
$sharing_content .='<a style="margin-left:2px; font-weight:bold;" class ="comentar" href="<?php comments_link(); ?>">Add a comment</a>';

$sharing_content .='<a style="margin-left:5px; font-weight:bold;" class ="comentar" href="<?php wp_list_comments(); ?>">View comments</a>';
```

The includes of the php module:

```
include_once dirname( __FILE__ ).'/sharing-sources.php';
```

I think that dont run because I have not added the include of the php wordpress function.

Any help? :-S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 issues - Your syntax is incorrect in that you shouldn't be using the PHP opening and closing tags, you are adding to the the variable `$sharing_content` so your syntax should be;

```
$sharing_content .='<a style="margin-left:2px; font-weight:bold;" class ="comentar" href="'. comments_link() .'">Add a comment</a>';
```

The first link to the comments for the current post should work. However, your second link won't work at all, you've just stuck `wp_list_comments();` in as the href value.  `wp_list_comments();` would be used to display all the comments of the current post in a template, not to link to them.  I'd suggest that your href value should be the post's url, the comments will be viewable there;

```
$sharing_content .= '<a style="margin-left:5px; font-weight:bold;" class ="comentar" href="'. the_permalink() .'">View comments</a>';
```

Comment: Is true that my code not is correct, but, If I use your code, when I click in the botton this redirect at home page and show in the teaser header of all post the permalink of the post :-S

Comment: @KikoBeats - Sorry maybe I wasn't clear (I'm assuming you are talking about the second example here?).  I was really saying that wp_list_comments(); was wrong and this would need to be replaced.  I've never used Jetpack sharedaddy, I don't know what it's doing or where that code would be used. I was just saying it would need changed out and suggested the_permalink();

Comment: What you could do is set up a page with a custom template that uses wp_list_comments(); and just link to that page directly.